# weird physics bug when a ball hits the left wall

Tags: python, physics

for some reason when a ball hits the left wall it gains momentum

i tried using "* -1" instead of "-"

heres the code

```py
y = y + vel_y
x = x + vel_x
vel_y = vel_y + 1
if y >= 900:
    y = 900
    vel_y = -(vel_y - 10)
if x >= 900:
    x = 900
    vel_x = -(vel_x - 10)
if y <= 100:
    y = 100
    vel_y = -(vel_y - 10)
if x <= 100:
    x = 100
    vel_x = -(vel_x - 10)
```

im using python and pygame

Comment: Could you explain your rational for what `vel_x = -(vel_x - 10)` is supposed to mean? Note that for `vel_x < 5`, that results in an increase in the absolute value of `vel_x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `vel_x` is negative when going left, the calculation `-(-vel_x - 10)` gives `vel_x + 10`, which will be bigger than the velocity before you hit the wall. Say the initial velocity is -50, you get `-(-50 - 10) = 50 + 10 = 60`. Make sure subtraction of the speed reduction makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using positive and negative velocity then subtracting decreases velocity or increases velocity depending on value of velocity, positive minus 10 decreases, negative minus 10 increases. If you want you could do like absolute value of velocity thing - 10 and with that in parentheses make it correct sign outside parentheses.